# What is the age of the students in Hope Academy?

Tags: danganronpa

Like I said in the title, how old are they when they are imprisoned in DG 1 and in other games and anime? Also, what is the age of warriors of hope and Komaru?

Comment: There's [a detailed fan-theory regarding timeline and DR casts' age by firefly20ffm](http://firefly20ffm.tumblr.com/post/56156894982/trying-to-figure-out-a-complete-dr-timeline).

Comment: @AkiTanaka I forgot this series already but is there a tentative non-spoiler answer like maybe they're year 1 or year 2 or something?